# how to initialize fixed-size integer numpy arrays in Cython?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, cython

How can one make empty numpy arrays of type `int` in Cython? The following works for me for double or float arrays:

```
# make array of size N of type float
cdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N)
# make array of size N of type int
cdef np.ndarray[int, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N)
```

However, if I try to do the same with int, it fails:

```
# this fails
cdef np.ndarray[np.int, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N)
# wanted to set first element to be an int
myarr[0] = 5
```

it gives the error:

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got 'double'

Since apparently `np.empty()` returns a double. I tried:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.int, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N, dtype=int)
```

but it gives the same error. How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Include the statement

```
cimport numpy as np
```

and declare the array as, say, `np.int32_t`:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N, dtype=np.int32)
```

You can drop the `32` from the type declarations, and use

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] myarr = np.empty(N, dtype=np.int)
```

but I prefer to be explicit about the size of the elements in a numpy array.

Note that I also added the dtype to `empty`; the default dtype of `empty` is `np.float64`.

Comment: Why doesn't this work with plain `int` or just `np.int` as opposed to `np.int32_t`?

Comment: The type argument of the ndarray declaration needs to be a C type, not a Python object type.  If you dig into the numpy cython header file `numpy.pxd`, you'll find that `np.int32_t` ultimately results in the declaration `signed int`.

Comment: could you explain why you use `dtype=np.int` and not `dtype=np.int32_t` when calling `np.empty`? the latter does not work

Answer (score 1):

Wierd!I got the same error when I tried. However, looking at the error message, I just changed the scope of the array creation to a function, and it compiles! I don't know the reason why this is happening, but .

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE_t
DTYPE=np.int

def new_array():
    cdef int length = 10
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] x = np.zeros([length], dtype=np.int)
    return x

x = new_array()
```

I think http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/language_basics.html#python-functions-vs-c-functions has some information related to scoping of python/c/mixed variables.